# UIImage to Hex Conversion in Objective C

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c

I have the following C# coding to convert an uploaded bitmap image to Hex. I need to follow the algorithm to come ip with the same goal in objective C. Assume I have a UIImageView with an image selected from the Picture gallery. I need to convert this selected image to Hex and write to a text file.

Someone please give me a help to convert this code to Objective C. I have some knowledge in IOS development but have not much knowledge in Image processing.

This is my code,

```
            Bitmap bm1 = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;

            int PictureWidth = pictureBox1.Image.Width;
            int PictureHeight = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
            int PictureX;
            int PictureY;

            int NVImageWidth;
            int NVImageHeight;

            NVImageWidth = PictureWidth;
            NVImageHeight = PictureHeight;

            int Quotient;
            int Remainder;
            int wp;

            wp = 0;

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("D:\\Test.txt");

            for (PictureX = 0; PictureX <= PictureWidth - 1; PictureX++)
            {
                for (PictureY = 0; PictureY <= NVImageHeight - 1; PictureY++)
                {
                    Color c1 = bm1.GetPixel(PictureX, PictureY);

                    if ((PictureY % 8) == 0)
                    {
                        wp = 0;
                        wp = (c1.G!=0) ? 0 : 1;
                    }
                    else if ((PictureY % 8) == 7)
                    {
                        wp = (wp << 1) | ((c1.G!=0) ? 0 : 1);
                        sw.Write(string.Format("%{0:x2}", wp));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        wp = (wp << 1) | ((c1.G!=0) ? 0 : 1);
                    }
                }
            }

            sw.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a suggestion:

First convert the UIImage to NSData. Then convert NSData to Hexadecimal.

So for example,

```
//converting to hexadecimal
    -(NSString*)hexRepresentationWithSpaces_AS:(BOOL)spaces
    {
        const unsigned char* bytes = (const unsigned char*)[self bytes];
        NSUInteger nbBytes = [self length];
        //If spaces is true, insert a space every this many input bytes (twice this many output characters).
        static const NSUInteger spaceEveryThisManyBytes = 4UL;
        //If spaces is true, insert a line-break instead of a space every this many spaces.
        static const NSUInteger lineBreakEveryThisManySpaces = 4UL;
        const NSUInteger lineBreakEveryThisManyBytes = spaceEveryThisManyBytes * lineBreakEveryThisManySpaces;
        NSUInteger strLen = 2*nbBytes + (spaces ? nbBytes/spaceEveryThisManyBytes : 0);

        NSMutableString* hex = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:strLen];
        for(NSUInteger i=0; i<nbBytes; ) {
            [hex appendFormat:@"%02X", bytes[i]];
            //We need to increment here so that the every-n-bytes computations are right.
            ++i;

            if (spaces) {
                if (i % lineBreakEveryThisManyBytes == 0) [hex appendString:@"\n"];
                else if (i % spaceEveryThisManyBytes == 0) [hex appendString:@" "];
            }
        }
        return [hex autorelease];
    }

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage.image);
NSString* hex = [imageData hexRepresentationWithSpaces_AS:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That's a great help.So, according to what you have mentioned above.i have to pass a UIImage-->convert it to NSData-->then call this hexRepresentationWithSpaces_AS function where it will return me an NSString which I can write to a text file... is that so? bdw,can u please clarify what the parameter passing to the function as "space". can you please share the concept used here, it would help me to understand your approach more. thanks in advance

Comment: yes. it is boolean, so either yes or no. If you want space, put YES, else NO.

Comment: thanks but what do u mean by saying " If you want space"? not clear to me. can you please explain bit?